# What is the best word (or term) to identify pronouncing W's for L's and R's?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, idiom-requests

Is there a specific/proper/technical term for it?  And not just the R-flop, but specifically the L-flop to W.

What would work here:

> “I'm watching Formula 1 on Sky Sports and the __________ of the Brit announcers is so annoying - it's *killing* me."
>
> “Billie Piper is so hot.  Her __________ in *Dr. Who* has me rubbing my legs together like a cricket.”

You get the idea.

- Rhotacism – I think related to other speech “impediments”, possibly too specific to the letter R, or at least not specific enough, I don't think
- Elmer Fudd Syndrome – too pejorative
- **Baby Talk** – perfect in above sentences, but I think reserved for intentional use.
- Johnathan Ross Syndrome - ?
- The L/R to W speech impediment - ?
- L-vocalization - ?
- “non-rhotic dialect r fronting” - ?

Ref.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld3A3QCpXd4
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6j63IyE-EM
- http://dialectblog.com/2011/05/26/the-trubbow-with-l-vocalization/
- http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ElmuhFuddSyndwome
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotacism
- http://dialectblog.com/2011/02/07/jonathan-ross-and-the-letter-r/

Comment: _Wabiawization_?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there isn't an official term to encompass both cases besides something general such as _speech impediment_.

Comment: _Johnathan Ross Syndrome_ was the precise name/wording that immediate sprung to my mind before I even read the body of the question itself.

Comment: @Janus: I've heard/seen the man himself referred to as *Johnathan Woss* many times (including, obviously, every time he says it! :). I can't specifically recall whether I've ever heard anyone call what he does ***wossing***, but that would seem such a natural coinage I prolly wouldn't remember it anyway.

Comment: [Burr](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burr) is related, but not really the same thing. (I found *burr* given as the translation of Hungarian *raccsolás*, which is a speech impediment where the subject is unable to properly roll his Rs, instead producing a sound more akin to H, almost like the CH in Bach.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L-vocalization is the term that would be used by linguists. In addition to British English, you can see the change in Polish and Brazilian Portuguese as well (a dark L is pronounced as a vowel or glide instead of as a lateral). Shakespeare himself made a little joke of this in *Hamlet*:

> Gravedigger: It must be se offendendo. It cannot be else. For here lies the point:
>   if I drown myself wittingly, it argues an act. And an act hath three
>   branches—it is to act, to do, to perform. **Argal**, she drowned herself
>   wittingly.

Received Pronunciation is said to be a non-rhotic because speakers do not pronounce the r at the end of words. I'd want to check with some of our UK contributors, but I think that it is a loss of r (and lengthening of the previous vowel) rather than a change from /r/ to /w/.

Comment: That’s only one of the two, though.

Comment: Maybe _“L/R-vocalization”_?  Anyway, _“Will Ferrell”_ as _“Wiwuw Fawuww”_, exactly as Johnathan Ross pronounces it in the link, is the most specific thing I'm talking about.  It's changing all the L's that is what I hear worst.  The R-thing mostly just seems like proper cockney.

Comment: It may be that the velarization of postvocalic English /l/, as well as the liprounding of the English /r/ in all rhotic positions, conspire to produce a neutralization of both resonants to the resonant /w/, which is just a rounded vowel in the velar position. I've never thought about it before, but they do dovetail nicely that way. I spose that's why Elmer Fudd's accent is so easy to mimic -- we've got natural categories already.

Comment: To clarify the Hamlet quote: the gravedigger means "ergo" but has misinterpreted the Latin pronunciation.

Answer (score 4):

**Liquid vocalization** is a general term encompassing vocalization of both /l/ and /r/ sounds.

This is the term used in Lisa J. Green's *African American English: A Linguistic Introduction* (2002), among others.

It's a simple combination of two linguistics terms:

1. **Liquid**.  This is defined in David Crystal's *Dictionary of Linguistics and Phonetics* (2008) as:

   > A term used by some phoneticians in the classification of speech sounds, referring collectively to all the apico-alveolar sounds of the type [l] and [r].
2. **Vocalization.**  From the same dictionary:

   > In phonetics, a term referring to the process of changing a consonant articulation so that it becomes more vowel-like. For example, some regional accents of English, such as Cockney, have vocalized final /-l/, so that /wel/ is pronounced as [weʊ].

So although it's not an especially common term, it should be readily understandable for linguists.

Answer (score 2):

Impediment.

a defect in a person's speech, such as a lisp or stammer.
noun: speech impediment; plural noun: speech impediments

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get your intention across by combining the terms *rhotacism* and *lambdacism* into ***lambdarhotacism***.

I see there is highly related word, although it does not have any *W* connotation: ***lallation***:

> A ***lallation*** (also called *cambia-letras* or *troca-letra*, "letter changer", in Latin American countries) is an imperfect enunciation of the letter "L", in which it sounds like "R" (or vice versa), as frequently found in infantile speech.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lallation)</sub>

Comment: I guess *lallation* would suggest the creation of the word ***wawation***.

Comment: Or, should that have been ***wawwation***?